# Firefox blocking with list and multiple pages

Tags: browser-addons, firefox

I have the following issue, i gathered what i called "leads" by browsing a lot of sites, but i would like to block the sites that i haved already looked for, something like putting it in a CSV or excel file and just blocked those URL so they wont appear.

Is there any firefox plugin that allow me to set a list of URL a just block them?

Answer (score 1):

The [BlockSite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blocksite/) plugin is what you are after. It will also disable links to those sites.

Have fun.

Comment: i already have a list of sites does it allow to load from a list?

Comment: @Necronet Yes. Read the instructions on how to on that link I gave you.